# Spring MVC 3 Validation not working

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I have a bean to validate using jsr-303 but the BIndingResult returns no error. every time it returns to the success view

My Bean is

```
public class User
{

    //@NotNull
    private int userId;   


    @NotNull
    @Size(min=3,max=100)
    private String userName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max=60)
    private String userFullName;
}
```

my controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user")
@Controller
public class UserController{

    @RequestMapping(value="/create",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createUserForm(Map model)
    {
        model.put("user",new User());
        return "createUserForm";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/create",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createUser  (@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user,BindingResult result,Map model)
    {
        if(result.hasErrors())
        {
            return "createRmsUserForm";
        }
        else
        {
            model.put("User",user);
            return "redirect:/home";

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- you need a javax.validation provider on your classpath (for example hibernate-validator-4.x.jar)
- you need to enable it in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. `<mvc:annotation-driven />` is the easiest way.

Comment: i have tried adding hibernate-validator-4.0.0.Beta1.jar and <mvc:annotation-driven /> is also added in the servlet-context.xml. but there is no change :(

Comment: show my your dispatcher servlet xml. Also, hibernate validator is not beta for a long time - grab a newer version.

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="com.pbl.rms" />
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
 <context:annotation-config />

Answer (score 2):

if you are using maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you show another page when error occurs? Try to return user to the same page: in your case `createUserForm` instead of `createRmsUserForm`.